# Python RegEx - How do I form a regex that contains a hyphen inside a word

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression to match "/page-2" or "/page-3" as part of a bigger URL such as http://domain.com/articles/page-number

So far, I have tried these combinations:
'/page-\d'
'/page-\d'
'\b/page-\d\b'

Please note, I am using the regex as part of the rules in the start_urls section in a Scrapy project. Any suggestions much appreciated. Here's a code snippet:

```
class NdtvXoloNewsItem(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ndtvxolonews"
    allowed_domains = ["http://gadgets.ndtv.com/tags/"]
    start_urls = ["http://gadgets.ndtv.com/tags/xolo/articles"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['\b/page\-\d\b']))]
```

Comment: + is a quantifier that specifies one or more

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!! all of them

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: So, is there no need to escape the hyphen or even the / that appears before "page"?

Comment: No not in python....do use `r` or `raw mode` for specifying ur regex

Comment: When I try all those combinations AND what vks suggested, it only crawls the url mentioned in the start_urls part. That is, only "http://gadgets.ndtv.com/tags/xolo/articles" page gets crawled. Not the subsequent ones like "http://gadgets.ndtv.com/tags/xolo/articles/page-2"

Comment: Are you sure `page-2` has really `-` character and not some weird Unicode hyphen?

Comment: ALWAYS put your regexps in raw strings. It doesn't always make a difference, but it very often does. Your code snippet is looking for "page-<digit>" surrounded by backspaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allowed_domains` should be just the domain name. You can filter to a specific path by including the start of the URL in the RegEx

```
class NdtvXoloNewsItem(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ndtvxolonews"
    allowed_domains = ["gadgets.ndtv.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://gadgets.ndtv.com/tags/xolo/articles"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['http://gadgets.ndtv.com/tags/.*/page\-\d+']))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'/page-\d+\b']))]
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: Tried it! Doesn't work :( only crawls the URL in start_url. Does it matter if I am using an old version of python? I am using the python 2.7 as of now since scrapy is compatible with ver 2.7 as of now.

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran try `r'.*?/page-\d+\b'` or `r'.*?/page-\d+$'`

Comment: No luck! Thanks for all your suggestions. I will take another good look at the code and figure out if something else is going wrong.

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran can you share the code how this regex is being applied